# Delphi: MAPI setting Mail Priority

Tags: email, delphi, mapi, jedi

I am using JclMapi to send an email with the default mail client.
Its all working fine, but i want to set the mail priority too. But i didnt find out how to set it yet.

Can anyone help me?

Thats my source code:

```
MAPIJclEmail := TJclEmail.Create;
MAPIJclEmail.Recipients.Add(RecipientsTo, '', rkTo, '');
if RecipientsCC <> '' then
  MAPIJclEmail.Recipients.Add(RecipientsCC, '', rkCC, '');
if RecipientsBCC <> '' then
  MAPIJclEmail.Recipients.Add(RecipientsBCC, '', rkBCC, '');
MAPIJclEmail.Subject := Subject;
MAPIJclEmail.Body := HtmlBody;
// Priority?
for i := Low(FileNames) to High(FileNames) do
  Result := AddFileAsAttachment(FileNames[i]);
MAPIJclEmail.Send;
```

Comment: I'd suggest you dropping MAPI and using any internet library to connect to SMTP servers directly

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but i am already able to send a mail over smtp - but besides this function the user want to check and edit the mail in his default mail client before sending it